# What did web services replace?

Tags: web-services

I was asked this question in an interview and had no idea. And I still don't. I thought they were created for this purpose, not to replace something that already exists. Any thoughts?

Comment: The question seems an incorrect one. But may be he wanted to hear smth. like sockets or abstracted out the remote communication. Anyhow I wouldn't like to work for guys who ask such questions at the interview

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In oversimplified terms web services 'replaced' older RPC technologies like COM+ and CORBA

Comment: I guess he wanted to know briefly the older services. Or maybe he was expecting me to explain the benefits of web services. Who knows?!

Comment: It isn't a great question. Either he had a specific set of technologies in mind that he or the company have replaced in the past (e.g. VB6/COM+ -> .NET/Web Services) or he wanted a more general discussion about RPC concepts. Or, as you say, who knows.

Answer (score 1):

CORBA might be what the interviewer had expected you to answer. Or maybe RMI for java2java communication.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the interviewer wanted to name some particular term but they improved the way different applications and systems communicate with each other.